# How can I get a URL that never expire in AWS Amplify Storage.get API function?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am implementing a blogging platform which user has to upload images for each content. I am wondering if I can during the upload I can get the permanent URL of the image as a response from AWS Amplify Storage.get function?

I want to know if this is a good idea?

```
Storage.get('img-sample.png', { expires: 9999999 })
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I wanted the URL because I will be saving it on the database. I don't want to call the Storage.get API function every time the postcontent is rendered because what if  there are multiple images inside a post content. That will make the application less reliable I think.

EDIT: base on the question of danielfranca

I think the application will be less reliable because having multiple images in one content and getting each images one by one using Storage.get API function. Can hangup the loading of the page in just one blog post

Comment: why do you think it would be less reliable?

Comment: @danielfranca because having multiple images in one content and getting each images one by one can hangup the loading of the page in just one blog post?

Comment: the Storage.get only returns the pre-signed URL, which is a non-expensive operation, it doesn't do anything fancy or extra steps... in any case you would need to request the actual image, whether you have the pre signed URL on the database or not.

Comment: so, I don't think you get any benefit on removing the expiration, just adding a security flaw.

Comment: @danielfranca ok let me try your Advice. Thank so much